# Why is it correct? Many is for negative sentences and questions

Tags: grammar, many-a

There is the sentence:

> I visited many European cities.

Why is this sentence correct?
"Many" is for negative sentences and questions.

Someone claims that you can use "many" in different cases as well. So, someone needs to read the info. The first links that I picked

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/many

https://test-english.com/explanation/a1/much-many-lot-little-few/

Instead of replying to me, they blocked me. I'm applauding!

Comment: Why do you think that _many_ is only for negative sentences?

Comment: Why would many indicate anything negative?

Comment: _Not many_ is for negative sentences! _Many_ simply means 'a large number of'. You could have found this in a dictionary.

Comment: Many a small town has a fascinating museum. Unique crafts are found in many places.

Comment: And if you're upset at downvotes, read [How do I ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Experts, read where u can use "many"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/many
https://test-english.com/explanation/a1/much-many-lot-little-few/

Comment: Very friendly forum, heheh

Answer (score 1):

The idea that “many” is for negative sentences alone is incorrect. “many” can quanitify the good, the bad, the ugly, the interesting, the beautiful, that which has promise or oppotunity.What are you trying to say?

Comment: Often students believe (or are led to) that *many* must only be used in questions and in negatives. *How many cinemas are there in your town?* *Not many.* *There aren't many.* In affirmative sentences the following will be taught: *There are some* and *There are a lot (of cinemas)*

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/many

https://test-english.com/explanation/a1/much-many-lot-little-few/

Comment: @Xanne, have u read these resources?